# Issue with lining up third level drop-down navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having a strange issue with lining up my third level navigation with it parent nav item on the left. It's just floating too high up when it pops out.

The menu in question is on one of our dev pages: [link](https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/leadership/planning/college_plan/index.php)

Planning > College Plan > */

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to solve the issue

```
.sub-nav li ul li ul {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sub-nav > ul li ul li:hover ul {
    margin-top: -52px;
}
```

The margin-top: -52px on .sub-nav > ul li ul li:hover ul is your culprit.